# SMS registration and login

Tags: plugin-development, user-registration

I want change default wordpress login/email/passwords registration to sms/otp (where sms will be the login (for example) and otp is a password). As well as restore passwords will be by sms only. Does anything existing solution here? or may be some have expiriences or advices how to realise it.

Answer (score 1):

[OTP Verification plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/miniorange-otp-verification/) verifies Email Address/Mobile Number of users by sending verification code(OTP) during registration. It removes the possibility of a user registering with fake Email Address/Mobile Number. This plugin checks the existence of the Email Address/Mobile Number and the ability of a user to access that Email Address/Mobile Number.

I have not used this plugin but may be with some modifications overriding the plugin helps convert the plugin in to your needs.

Hope this plugin helps!